# Is there any geometric explanation of relationship between Integral and derivative?

Tags: integration, derivatives

It is said integral is anti-derivative, derivative is tangent of graph function in each point on the function and integral is the area of the region in the $xy$-plane bounded by the graph.

I can not understand the relationship between these, can anyone help me? I want understand the relationship between area and slope of tangent line.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/15302/85969).

Comment: You can think integral as a sum or accumulated value (in the sense of distributions) and derivative the representation of each member of the sum. Its easier to see taking finite intervals instead of infinitesimals.

Comment: I imagine most modern calculus textbooks (the thousand-page monsters) have a few pages devoted to intuition for this point.  Probably near the "Fundamental Theorem of Calculus", which should be listed in the index.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the area under a curve the integral?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15294/why-is-the-area-under-a-curve-the-integral)

Comment: @Hakim The linked question focuses on why integral is area, and to the extent that the answer relates areas to tangents the explanation isn't geometric.

Comment: @Conifold Yes, but it links it to differentiation at the same time.

Comment: The youtuber 3blue1brown has a video called what does area have to do with slope, he explains intuitively and geometrically the relationship. here's the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnJqaIESC2s