# What is the $d$ used in calculus?

Tags: calculus

I know the letter $d$ is commonly used in calculus and represents a derivative. 
Does this $d$ act as a variable that can be simplified or as a function of another variable?

Comment: $d/dx$ is an operator. The domain of the operator is set of functions with derivatives at every point of the domain, with the range being another set of functions.

Comment: Berkeley called these or somethings similar "ghosts of departed quantities"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the $d$ in Leibnitz's notation is often used as a variable in operations on derivatives (see below), this is merely a convenience of the notation. The $d$ itself simply stands to indicate which is the independent variable of the derivative ($x$) and which is the function for which the derivative is taken ($y$). $\frac{d}{dx}$ itself is an operator on function $y$.

The second derivative (the derivative of a derivative), is written as if it is the product of two derivatives $\frac{d}{dx}\times\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ (with parentheses being assumed in the denominator $\frac{d^2y}{(dx)^2}$)

The chain rule can also be understood as a form of multiplication, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\times\frac{du}{dx}$, with the $u$ canceling.

However, it must always be held in consideration that the *reason* for these equalities is not derived from such symbol manipulation but rather from rigorous proof. They are convenient notations which are understood to represent a deeper meaning.

Comment: You might also be interested in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1235718/94971) that I gave to a similar question, mainly related to the last part of this answer regarding the lack of rigour in the appealing symbol manipulation.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer in regard to Bos's work on contradiction in Leibniz's notation is also fascinating.