# Help in the corollary of the first theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm reading fundamental theorem of calculus in a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part)
and I didn't understand the meaning of the corollary:

[image]

If  $F(x)$ is defined to be $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\ dt$ why do we need the theorem of calculus to prove this? using the definition of the $F(x)$ we see that $F(b)=\int_a^b f(t)\ dt$ and $F(a)=\int_a^a f(t)\ dt=0$.

What am I missing?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925465/is-there-any-geometric-explanation-of-relationship-between-integral-and-derivati/925559#925559