# I can't understand the relation between derivative and integration.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Why (not how for how have been a proof) the integration of derivative of a function give us the function :|
let me explain more with pictures.

like here we have the derivative of $x^2$,

[image]

but how the hell does the area of under it give us the $f(x)$

[image]

I can't understand the intuition of it or something.

Comment: @AnotherUser: The images are plots. Perhaps OP should have more exposition, but these plots cannot be reduced to anything searchable.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: OP: Why did you revert my edit to inline your images? Doing so makes your question *less* legible, not more.

Comment: @BrianTung i couldn't ask it without images

Comment: @AnotherUser i will do it in my next questions thanks

Comment: @BrianTung bad internet connection. thanks for editing

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what your last edit did. I had edited your post so that the images appear in the body of the post (rather than as links), because you lack the reputation to do so. Then you rolled back my edit so the images were removed and made links again. You took away your own images, rather than leaving them in, in other words. Just be careful with your edits, is all I'm saying.

Comment: "i will do it in my next questions thanks". Why don't you do it with this question? It is totally permitted, even expected, that new users will have to make a couple of edits to get their first question up to the standards required.

Comment: There are plenty of explanations online for the fundamental theorem of calculus, including [the Wikipedia plot summary on FTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), [questions on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-intuitive-explanation-of-the-Fundamental-Theorem-of-Calculus), and some questions on this very site, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333441/the-meaning-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus). Please take a look at those, and then come back if you have trouble understanding them. Being specific will help us help you.

Comment: I think maybe OP couldn't see what you put when you edited because they have bad internet connection . Idk . Just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, this is because the total is the sum of its parts.

Consider a differentiable function $f$ and let $x, y$ be such that $y=f(x)$.

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus states that $$f(b)-f(a)=\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)dx$$ where $f'$ is the derivative of $f$.

The left hand side represents the difference between two values of $f$. The expression $f'(x)dx$ represents a small step in the $y$ direction, i.e. $dy=f'(x)dx$ and the integral sums up those small changes to get the total change.

Therefore, we can translate the above theorem to say that the total change in $f$ that occurs when $x$ goes from $a$ to $b$ can be computed by summing all of the small changes that occurred.